# Sum elapsed hours and minutes in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheets where I note down estimated times and elapsed times.

A2 > A26 has estimated times formatted with H:mm (minutes with leading 0).
B2 > B26 has spent times formatted with H:mm (minutes with leading 0).

I am trying to do a sum of estimated times and spent times for each column.
Have searched all around but everywhere I found a solution it is with "clock in" and "clock out" times which I do not have.

My cells are formatted in Google Spreadsheets as "Elapsed hours (1):Elapsed minutes (01)"

Hope someone can help me here as I am very stuck.

Link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JzIPEeTvVSAzXCzoQIfWLoeEq5sZZKdF80pxitdxChs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you expect an Excel solution?

Comment: Alas both of our answers are wrong :-) If you try to convert 24:53 (or any time >24 hours) to time, you lose the part of it which is a whole number of days (i.e. a multiple of 24 hours). I may have to delete my answer because only the approach of @player0 will work for the reason just stated and only if the answer calculates hours and minutes separately.

Comment: On second thoughts i can adjust my answer, but still don't know why original sheet shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(1*("kl. "&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A26; ":"; "."))); "[h]:mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. Would not have found that out in a million years.
Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks again. I did infact look for the "accept" button, but i guess the eyes are the first body part to go blind. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I don't understand why these formulas don't work on the original sheet, but the modified formulas (allowing for times>24 hours) are:

```
=sumproduct(timevalue(A2:A26)+quotient(A2:A26,1))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(timevalue(A2:A26)+quotient(A2:A26,1)))
```

On my sheet:

[image]

Comment: So why is that? It works fine when I copy and paste the data across to my own sheet.

Comment: norwegian sheet... and there the time is `kl. hh.mm.ss` not the usual `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose they could change the locale, but they probably don't want to.

Comment: I did try to get rid of "kl." and change it to hh:mm, but whenever i did change it, it went back to the kl. hh.mm.ss value again, wich is not even correct norwegian. We use hh:mm:ss.